# Why I am not able to use two screen for registration in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have register screen in SwiftUI, and I want to use two register screen for users, one view have mail and password, and other view have name surname and occupation, but I am still do not understand how I will connect both register view, any idea?

**RegistrationViewModel:**

```
enum RegistrationState {
    case successfullyRegistered
    case failed(error: Error)
    case na
}

protocol RegistrationViewModel {
    func create()
    var service: RegistrationService { get }
    var state: RegistrationState { get }
    var hasError: Bool { get }
    var newUser: RegistrationCredentials { get }
    init(service: RegistrationService)
}

final class RegistrationViewModelImpl: ObservableObject, RegistrationViewModel {
    
    let service: RegistrationService
    @Published var state: RegistrationState = .na
    @Published var newUser = RegistrationCredentials(email: "",
                                                     password: "",
                                                     firstName: "",
                                                     lastName: "",
                                                     occupation: "")
    @Published var hasError: Bool = false

    private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    init(service: RegistrationService) {
        self.service = service
        setupErrorSubscription()
    }
    
    func create() {    
        service
            .register(with: newUser)
            .sink { [weak self] res in
            
                switch res {
                case .failure(let error):
                    self?.state = .failed(error: error)
                default: break
                }
            } receiveValue: { [weak self] in
                self?.state = .successfullyRegistered
            }
            .store(in: &subscriptions)}}
 
private extension RegistrationViewModelImpl {
    
    func setupErrorSubscription() {
        $state
            .map { state -> Bool in
                switch state {
                case .successfullyRegistered,
                     .na:
                    return false
                case .failed:
                    return true}}
            .assign(to: &$hasError)}}
```

**firstscreen:**

```
struct RegisterView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = RegistrationViewModelImpl(
        service: RegistrationServiceImpl()
    )
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 32) {
                
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    
                    InputTextFieldView(text: $viewModel.newUser.email,
                                       placeholder: "Email",
                                       keyboardType: .emailAddress,
                                       systemImage: "envelope")
                    InputPasswordView(password: $viewModel.newUser.password,
                                      placeholder: "Password",
                                      systemImage: "lock")
                }
                ButtonView(title: "Next") {
                    viewModel.create()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.hasError,
                   content: {
                    
                    if case .failed(let error) = viewModel.state {
                        return Alert(
                            title: Text("Error"),
                            message: Text(error.localizedDescription))
                    } else {
                        return Alert(
                            title: Text("Error"),
                            message: Text("Something went wrong"))
                    }})}}}
```

**secondscreen:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondRegisterView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = RegistrationViewModelImpl(
        service: RegistrationServiceImpl()
    )
    var body: some View { 
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 32) {
                VStack(spacing: 16) {
                    InputTextFieldView(text: $viewModel.newUser.firstName,
                                       placeholder: "First Name",
                                       keyboardType: .namePhonePad,
                                       systemImage: nil)
                    
                    InputTextFieldView(text: $viewModel.newUser.lastName,
                                       placeholder: "Last Name",
                                       keyboardType: .namePhonePad,
                                       systemImage: nil)
                    InputTextFieldView(text: $viewModel.newUser.occupation,
                                       placeholder: "Occupation",
                                       keyboardType: .namePhonePad,
                                       systemImage: nil)
                }
                
                ButtonView(title: "Sign up") {
                    viewModel.create()
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
            .navigationTitle("Register")
            .applyClose()
            .alert(isPresented: $viewModel.hasError,
                   content: {
                    
                    if case .failed(let error) = viewModel.state {
                        return Alert(
                            title: Text("Error"),
                            message: Text(error.localizedDescription))
                    } else {
                        return Alert(
                            title: Text("Error"),
                            message: Text("Something went wrong"))
                    }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once your `create` function is done and it is successful, then you will move the user to the second screen.

Comment: @Rob, tnx so much for ur comment, how it will?

Comment: When the state is `viewModel.state == .successfullyRegistered` then move the user to the next screen.

Comment: @Rob, tnx but is it possible u give clear answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in these declarations in your views:

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = RegistrationViewModelImpl(...)
```

In `RegisterView` and `SecondRegisterView` you are using two different instances of your view model, so you will have two different sets of data between your views.

What you need to do is to create only once your view model in the parent view of your app (the view that calls the registration views), then *pass* the view model to both views.

In your parent view (the one that calls `RegisterView` and `SecondRegisterView`):

```
    // Use this declaration ONLY ONCE in your code for registration purposes

    @StateObject private var viewModel = RegistrationViewModelImpl(
        service: RegistrationServiceImpl()
    )
```

In `RegisterView` and in `SecondRegisterView`, replace the command above with:

```
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: RegistrationViewModelImpl
```

When calling both views from the parent view, pass your view model, like this:

```
RegisterView(viewModel: viewModel)
```

and

```
SecondRegisterView(viewModel: viewModel)
```

Comment: tnx so much for ur answer, I am use ` @StateObject private var viewModel = RegistrationViewModelImpl(
        service: RegistrationServiceImpl()
    )` for RegisterView and  `@ObservedObject var viewModel: RegistrationViewModelImpl` for SecondRegisterView, right?

Comment: I will use     viewModel.create() for both button?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how your code works, but you need to create the user only once. The view model will be the same for both users, so `viewModel.newUser` will be the same in both views. Careful not to create two different `newUser`s...

Comment: I understand but I do not know how I will use button for both screen?

Comment: Use `create()` in the first view, make another function in the view model (like `updateSurnameAndOccupation`), to use in the second view's button, that will store the values of surname and occupation in the view model.

Comment: I do all,  firebase keep mail,  but still I am not able save name surname..., I guess I don't use correctly buttons .